# Cant add a marker to Google Map on tap-ionic 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am having trouble finding a way to add a marker to google maps in my Ionic 2 application. I basically want to add a marker to google maps which is set to the center of the map by default when a user opens the application like Uber. Also if a user chooses to drag the map and look around, it sets the coordinates to the users current position just like Uber. I have tried researching on this but I didn't find any tutorial or documentation on how to to do it. I am using ionic 2 for my application with Angular2. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/ This came up as the first item when I searched and it shows how to add markers to google maps

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so that it would easy for guiding